# Python asyncio await-for timeout doesn't work for infinite task

Tags: python, async-await, timeout, infinite

In Python 3.8, I think I understand why the `forever` function below won't also timeout after 1 second unless I include the `asyncio.sleep(1)`.  It's because it starts executing after it comes off the queue and no other task on the queue gets run because it never blocks?

What I need to accomplish is to call some function (like forever) provided by a user.  They may give me a function that never returns (e.g. it infinitely loops and doesn't block).  So how do I get the effect I want of calling the user function and allowing it to run until a timeout?

```
import asyncio

async def long_time():
    # Sleep for one hour
    await asyncio.sleep(3600) 
    print('yay!')

async def forever():
    while True:
        pass
        #await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    # Wait for at most 1 second
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(long_time(), timeout=1.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout 1!')
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(forever(), timeout=1.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout 2!')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

Async/await is using a single thread to switch between async tasks (event loop, a queue).

Your task doesn't time out cause your `forever` completely blocks the thread by executing infinitely in a synchronous way and not allowing any other async task to take over (or any other code in the same thread). If you anticipate that there could be some functions provided by a user that will contain very long synchronous computations then you should use a separate [process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to run such a function.

You could in theory use a separate thread instead of a process but not in CPython because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock#:%7E:text=In%20CPython%2C%20the%20global%20interpreter,executing%20Python%20bytecodes%20at%20once.&text=The%20GIL%20is%20controversial%20because,multiprocessor%20systems%20in%20certain%20situations.). Only one thread can execute code at a time with GIL.